# Can't read all the lines of a file even when a line with the same structure has been read before with C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read some text files and put every word in a different variable. For some reason, which I can not find, the files are not being read to the end of the file, it stops suddenly instead of reading all the lines. The line where the file stopped being read has the structure of a previous line which was read without problem previously and therefore I am confused without seeing where the problem is.

The file I'm trying to read to test the code, can be seen: [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~ajh/courses/cpsc513/assign-cmbcmp-bdd/ISCAS85/DATA/c17.isc). The only lines I can read are the following:

```
    1     1gat inpt    1   0      >sa1
    2     2gat inpt    1   0      >sa1
    3     3gat inpt    2   0 >sa0 >sa1
    8     8fan from     3gat      >sa1
    9     9fan from     3gat      >sa1
    6     6gat inpt    1   0      >sa1
    7     7gat inpt    1   0      >sa1
   10    10gat nand    1   2      >sa1
     1     8
   11    11gat nand    2   2 >sa0 >sa1
```

The code I made to read it, is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line, netlist;
    string name, type, fsa0, fsa1, temp;
    int address, fanout, fout, fin, *FIN, max_node = 0;

    cout << "Wich Netlist you want to use?" << endl;
    cin >> netlist;

    ifstream file(netlist.c_str());
    if (file.is_open()) {
      while (getline(file, line)) {
        int temfalha = 0;
        long pfile; // conferir posição em file
        if ( line[0] != '*' ) {
          name = type = temp = fsa0 = fsa1 = "@";
          address = fanout = fout = fin = 0;
          file >> address >> name >> type;
          // checar se existe falha
          pfile = file.tellg(); //coloca em pfile a posição em que o ponteiro está.
          char a;
          for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                file >> a;
                if (a == '>') {
                  temfalha += 1;
                  //break;
                }
          }
          file.seekg(pfile); //coloca o ponteiro na posição pfile

          if ( type == "from") {
               file >> fanout >> temp;
               if (temfalha>0) {
                    file >> fsa0;
                    if ( temfalha == 1) {
                        if (fsa0 == ">sa0" ) { fsa1 = "@"; }
                        else { fsa1 = fsa0; fsa0 = "@"; }
                        if ( temfalha == 2) { file >> fsa1; }
                    }
               }
          } else if  (type == "inpt") {
               file >> fout >> fin;
               if (temfalha>0) {
                    file >> fsa0;
                    if ( temfalha == 1) {
                        if (fsa0 == ">sa0" ) { fsa1 = "@"; }
                        else { fsa1 = fsa0; fsa0 = "@"; }
                        if ( temfalha == 2) { file >> fsa1; }
                    }
               }
          } else {
               file >> fout >> fin;
               if (temfalha>0) {
                    file >> fsa0;
                    if ( temfalha == 1) {
                        if (fsa0 == ">sa0" ) { fsa1 = "@"; }
                        else { fsa1 = fsa0; fsa0 = "@"; }
                        if ( temfalha == 2) { file >> fsa1; }
                    }
               }
               FIN = new int[fin];
               for (int i= 0; i < fin; i++) file >> FIN[i];
          }
          if ( address > max_node )
             max_node = address;
          cout << address <<" "<< name <<" "<< type <<" "<< fanout <<" "<< temp <<" "<< fout <<" "<< fin <<" "<< fsa0 <<" "<< fsa1 <<" "<< endl;
        }
      }
      cout << max_node << endl;
    } else { cout << "File not found" << endl; }

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

ps.: the "@" present in the code, is a character I chose to fill blank spaces of the file.

Do you guys can see where the problem is? I'm new with C++, so, Thank you for all help.

Comment: Can you expand on "it stops suddenly" please?

Comment: One `new` , no `delete`, you've got a memory leak.

Comment: You read line by line from the file, but you don't actually parse that line, instead you read *again* from the file. That makes you loose a lot of data in the file.

Comment: Start simple - pare your problem down to a simpler case - for example, input of just one column.  When you have that working, scale up to more columns of input.  Not only will this improve your own understanding of what's happening, it will make it easier for you to post meaningful minimal examples in questions (I think that the sample in this question is much more than minimal).

Comment: @AndyNewman It read the first line, the second, the third, and so on, but in the 11th line it stop reading (I can't see the 12th and the other lines after that). This line has a structure like the 10th line and it was read all right.

Comment: @Quentin all the time I creat an array with <code>new</code> I have to <code>delete</code> it ? <br/>  Toby Speight I know is not that simple to read so much columns. What I'm doing is using the Debbug option of CodeBlocks to try to find the problem, but not success yet.

Comment: @LeonardoAlves Yes. Specifically, you need to `delete` what you `new` and `delete[]` what you `new[]`. Better yet, let standard containers like `std::vector` handle that for you.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem because I don't have the interest to actually run your code in a debugger, but it looks like you have the following code in more than one place: `if (temfalha == 2) { file >> fsa1; }` where the `if` clause will never be true because the test is inside another `if` block that is only entered when `(temfalha == 1)`.

Comment: I'll do that now. Thank you @Quentin I'm studying std::vector now because after I'm able to read the whole file I will create an array with all the content that the variable had during the read of the file.

Comment: Good point @MichaelBurr you right. I change that to (ps.: I'll try to show the code on this comment, but I don't know how to highlight it). I took off the if case of:   temfalha == 2    . The    if's    are like this now:    if (temfalha > 0 && temfalha == 1) {     and after that If I created another one with this case:    if (temfalha > 0 && temfalha == 2) { file >> fsa1; }    . Still can't read the whole file :(

Comment: "but in the 11th line it stop reading (I can't see the 12th and the other lines after that)."   ...   it does not just stop reading though, does it?  Does it return 0 from the getline function, or does it throw an exception, or what?  Where exactly does it stop and in what way?  A debugger will tell you this, or lots of additional cout statements.

Comment: @AndyNewman I debbuged the code and the problem was the allocation of the words in the variables. A variable at `if (temfalha > 0 && temfalha == 2) { file >> fsa1; }` was missing and this was preventing the code to read the rest of the lines. I fixed it. I don't know how to explain this in a better understandable way because I'm new to C++. Thank you guys, for the tips and for show me where was the erros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then doing `getline`, you read one line into the `line` variable *and advance the file pointer*. Thus then you later do `file >> address >> name >> type;`, you are reading the second line of your file. The data on the line read by `getline` is lost. What you can do instead, is to use `stringstream` to read data from string:

```
while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    if (line[0] != '*')
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> address >> name >> type;
        /* work with iss here */
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed every `file.` for `iss.` after adding the lines you'd suggest and add `#include <sstream>` on the header and it return me a lot of 0's (zeros) and @s (cout). The only thing being showed is '>sa0' sometimes.

Comment: I fixed the code, and using istringstream it reads only the first line. Maybe because all the variables of line isn't all string type?